# Why do constructors have to have a public and not internal visibility?

Tags: solidity

Only initializes the contract, and I don't understand why it is not an internal function. With this, is more cheap the cost of the gas insted implementing a public function

API from Solidity :

```
 // This is the constructor which registers the
        // creator and the assigned name.
    constructor(bytes32 _name) public {
            // State variables are accessed via their name
            // and not via e.g. `this.owner`. Functions can
            // be accessed directly or through `this.f`,
            // but the latter provides an external view
            // to the function. Especially in the constructor,
            // you should not access functions externally,
            // because the function does not exist yet.
            // See the next section for details.
        owner = msg.sender;
    
        // We do an explicit type conversion from `address`
        // to `TokenCreator` and assume that the type of
        // the calling contract is `TokenCreator`, there is
        // no real way to check that.



 creator = TokenCreator(msg.sender);
    name = _name;
}
```

Comment: if you want to make it internal then how you gonna access the initialised e.g. owner, creator outside the constructor?

Comment: But could it be external?